# AJAX performance issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

We have developed a website using ASP.NET 4.0.
AJAX functions work with no latency in intranet. But when it was moved to Internet, AJAX has become very slow. And the time it they take is inconstant as well.

So far I've done: 
I added following code to the ScriptManager

```
ScriptMode="Release" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="False"
```

And added following to the web.config

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>
</scripting>
```

Still no luck.

The data getting transferred is only 82KBs, but it takes 4-7 seconds.
Can anybody let us know what could be done to improve AJAX performance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has no relation to Ajax. most probably the issue is to do with network latency. you can check this If the client machine where you are making the requests is too far from the server which serves them

Comment: Page loads in less than 1 second. But for the AJAX function it takes 4-7 seconds. So it cannot be network latency.

Comment: and the webserver that is serving the requests is the same for both requests?

Comment: yes, we have written simple selectindexchanged and textchange events

Comment: then other thing that comes to my mind is that your company's proxy server may be performing complex and time consuming validations whenever the content is requested outside Intranet. Page load times can still be less for HTML pages, but Ajax requests are the prime contenders to be under the scanner of proxy servers.

Comment: According to our network team there is no complex filtering or anything. It's squid server, being used mainly to block some sites.